# What's a simple to implement Javascript or Flash-based tool for adding rotating images to a static website?

Tags: web

I'd like to find a free or inexpensive tool for adding images that change at intervals to a small school's webpage. I'm thinking of something very much like the Wordpress plugin [JS Banner Rotate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/js-banner-rotate/), but for static websites.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with animated GIFs, I ask you...

Comment: I'm looking to use jpgs, and to have flexibility about which photos I use, and to do it all with minimum programming skill and time. Of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

[I built this](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/slideshow/), which uses multiple panels. You can easily modify it for a single panel or multiple one.

It basically uses a image and a CSS background. It sets the background to the current image, then hides, swaps and fades-in a new image. Built using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

this should be pretty easy, no need for any libraries or anything just a few lines of javascript.

lets say on your site you have a directory full of images that you want to rotate

```
/web_root/images/rotate
```

with images named like this:

```
/web_root/images/rotate/img1.jpg
/web_root/images/rotate/img2.jpg
/web_root/images/rotate/img3.jpg
...
```

Then on your page you have an **img** that you want to rotate the images through.

```
<img id="rotator" src="images/rotate/img1.jpg"></img>
```

then add an onload event to your document **body** like

```
<body onload='start_rotate'>...
```

then somewhere in your **`<head>`** define a script section containing

```
var num_of_images = ...;
var timeout = 1000;
function start_rotate() {
    window.setTimeout('rotate()', timeout );
}
function rotate() {
    window.setTimeout('rotate()', timeout );
    var im = document.getElementById('rotator');
    var index = im.src.substring(im.src.indexof('.')-1, 1);
    var next_index = index + 1 % num_of_images;
    im.src = "images/rotate/img" + next_index +".jpg";
}
```

i probably have some syntax errors but this should illustrate the id, just set a timeout to swap the image every 1000 milliseconds.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Canvas, hands down the best way to do this.